# How To Retrieve LONGBLOB from MySQL in C# without datatype size but only datatype longblob

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

hello guys i want to retrieve LONGBLOB from MySQL in C#  without datatype size but only datatype longblob.i can save in mysql use longblob but i can retrieve it again.

I have created a table named 'dataalis' in that,

```
CREATE TABLE  `Wajah`.`dataalis` (
`No` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`Nama` varchar(45) default NULL,
`Keterangan` varchar(600) default NULL,
`Gambar` longblob,
PRIMARY KEY  (`No`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And

```
nama = namatxt.Text;
            keterangan = keterangantxt.Text;
            db = new DBConnect();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            int fileLength = (int)fs.Length;
            byte[] rawdata = new byte[fileLength];
            fs.Read(rawdata, 0, (int)fileLength);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            String sql = "insert into dataalis (Nama,Keterangan,Gambar) values(@Nama,@Keterangan,@Gambar)";
            cmd.Connection = db.getConnection();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama", nama);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keterangan", keterangan);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gambar", rawdata);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            fs.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Tersimpan","Peringatan");
```

to save image to mysql

and i have try to retrieve longblob image use this code

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = db.getConnection();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from datamulut";
            data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (data.Read())
            {
                int fileSize = data.GetInt32(data.GetOrdinal("size"));
                string name = data.GetString(data.GetOrdinal("Keterangan"));
                byte[] rawData = new byte[fileSize];
                data.GetBytes(data.GetOrdinal("Gambar"), 0, rawData, 0, fileSize);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(rawData);
                images.Add(Image.FromStream(ms));
                gambar1.Image = images[0];
                hasil1txt.Text = (name);
            }
            data.Close();
```

in that code i not use a filesize data only longblob.how i can retrieve image without filezie only longblob data?